# Insert to a SQL Server CE database

Tags: c#, insert, sql-server-ce

How do you insert into a table in a `.sdf` database?

I've tried the following:

```
string connection = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\InvoiceDatabase.sdf";
SqlCeConnection cn = new SqlCeConnection(connection);

try
{
   cn.Open();
}
catch (SqlCeException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Connection failed");
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    Application.ExitThread();
}

string clientName = txt_ClientName.Text;
string address = txt_ClientAddress.Text;
string postcode = txt_postcode.Text;
string telNo = txt_TelNo.Text;

string sqlquery = ("INSERT INTO Client (Name,Address,Postcode,Telephone_Number)Values(" + clientName + "','" + address + "','" + postcode + "','" + telNo + ")");
SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(sqlquery, cn);

try {
  int affectedRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

  if (affectedRows > 0)
  {
     txt_ClientAddress.Text = "";
     txt_ClientName.Text = "";
     txt_postcode.Text = "";
     txt_TelNo.Text = "";
     MessageBox.Show("Client: " + clientName + " added to database. WOoo");
  }
}
catch(Exception){
    MessageBox.Show("Insert Failed.");
}
```

But it doesn't seem to matter what i do it just shows "Insert Failed".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please catch the concret exception and post the message here

Answer (score 2):

You forgot opening quotation mark on the first value.

```
Values(" + clientName + "','"
```

change to:

```
Values('" + clientName + "','"
```

But this is generally a bad way to build query. Use parametrized query instead.
See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlcecommand.parameters(v=vs.80).aspx

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show(ex);
}
```

Will give you more info on error.

Answer (score 2):

It is the same old story. When you build a sql command concatenating string these kinds of errors abund. And the simple syntax problem is not the worst. The [Sql Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-this-sql-injection-work) is the most dangerous one.

Please build your query in this way

```
string sqlquery = ("INSERT INTO Client (Name,Address,Postcode,Telephone_Number)" + 
                   "Values(@client,@address, @postcode, @tel)";
SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(sqlquery, cn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@client", clientName);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", address);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postcode", postcode);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tel", telNo);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

As others have already said your syntax error is caused by omitting the initial single quote. But you could have other errors. For example, what about a client called `O'Hara`?. Now you have a single quote inside the clientname and this wreak havoc your string concatenation. 
Instead a parameter will be accurately parsed and every problematic character found will be treated appropriately (in this case doubling the single quote)

Comment: +1000000 if I could - couldn't agree more; if anyone today is still teaching students to concatenate together their SQL statement - he should be tickled to death with a feather.....

Comment: @marc_s: I think a spoon would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL statement is incorrect.

```
string sqlquery = ("INSERT INTO Client (Name,Address,Postcode,Telephone_Number)Values('" + clientName + "','" + address + "','" + postcode + "','" + telNo + "')");
```

Take this. You forgot the ' at the beginning and the end of the values

Answer (score 0):

To insert data into Sql, data type should be considered. If you insert a string value (varchar) you have to surround it by single quotation, like '"+full_Name+"', but integer type doesn't need this. example

```
string myQuery = "INSERT INTO Persons (phone, fullname) VALUES ("+telNo+",'"+full_Name+"')";
```

where full name is string variable and phone number is only number.